# how can i install touch driver for chuwi hi8 air

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-touch

Hello I am trying to install touch driver for my chuwi hi8 air tablet, using the programs in this link: https://github.com/onitake/gslx680-acpi

I cloned the git then I wrote `make` command after that.

Then I executed `insmod ./gslx680_ts_acpi.ko`

But when i checked `dmesg` I found this error :

```
[  257.261030] gslx680_ts_acpi: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  257.261193] gslx680_ts_acpi: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  257.272214] gslx680 i2c-MSSL1680:01: gsl_ts_probe: got a device named MSSL1680:01 at address 0x40, IRQ 184, flags 0x0
[  257.272304] gslx680 i2c-MSSL1680:01: Direct firmware load for silead_ts.fw failed with error -2
[  257.272309] gslx680 i2c-MSSL1680:01: gsl_ts_probe: failed to load firmware: -2
[  257.286110] gslx680: probe of i2c-MSSL1680:01 failed with error -2
```

can some one can explain with steps, how can i install this touch driver ? thanks.

oh and my ubuntu version is: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 0):

While it's not plain from the linked instructions, since `insmod` makes system-level changes, you must run `insmod` as `root`:

```
sudo insmod ./gslx680_ts_acpi.ko
```

Comment: i did write sudo same error

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this thread is four years old.. but I don't think running insmod as root will fix that issue. It's kind of implied that he was using root to compile and insert the module. It's more likely a kernel security issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975377/kvm-module-verification-failed-signature-and-or-required-key-missing-taintin